# How to access members of class from a page Load class in c#

Tags: c#

I have two classes in my project like this below:

```
//Class A
public class CarHelper
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string Colour {get;set;}
        public string Manufacturer {get;set;}
    }

    public Car GetDetails()
    {   
        Car c = new Car();
        var query = //querying from db here
        c.Colour = query.Colour;
        c.Manufacturer= query.Manufaturer;
        return c;
    }
}

//Class B
//here i have a page load method like this:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarHelper car = new CarHelper();
    var getCarManufacturer = car.Manufacturer; //<< stuck here
    //how would I get the car manufacturer here above?
}
```

As you can see above, whats the best way to access the members from class A?

Comment: Create a field or property in your page/form class and store the value or reference to `car` there. I highly recommend you pick up a c# book or tutorial. I would also recommend against nesting type `Car` inside `CarHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've created `GetDetails()` method which is `public` you can use it to retrieve `Car` object like so :

```
CarHelper carHelper = new CarHelper();
Car car = carHelper.GetDetails();
var carManufacturer = car.Manufacturer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Car` is a nested class under class `CarHelper` and thus needs to be initialized different way using fully qualified name like

```
CarHelper.Car car = new CarHelper.Car();
var getCarManufacturer = car.Manufacturer;
```

Since you aren't initializing the object your `car.Manufacturer` will end up being `null` as default value for reference type